# deploying node application on existing heroku app

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, heroku-cli

I'm trying to deploy me node application which is running sucessfully running on localhost. For this, I have installed heroku cli on my machine, and I'm opening GIT cli to do the following:

1. Heroku Login -- successful
2. git push heroku master -- trying to push to an existing heroku app.
   I've already deleted the heroku app it is refering to. Still it is pointing to the same app.
3. Even after reopening the git cli, it is pointing me to that and push is failing (git push heroku master)

Here the question is,

1. How to point my git to a newly created heroku app (everytime I'm creating a new app not knowing the command to point to the existing app)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 4 steps recommended in link may help u out with the cache - https://coderwall.com/p/jjcpra/clean-heroku-npm-cache

Comment: Thanks, The following command helped and resolved that particular issue
--------
heroku config:unset CACHE

Answer (score 2):

The easier way to add your heroku app remote reference is running the command below from your git folder:

```
heroku git:remote -a name-of-your-heroku-app
```

to verify if the remote heroku ref was correctly added you can run:

```
git remote -v
```

Answer (score 0):

When running the application using the heroku open command, facing the following issue. Any clue where i went wrong..?

2018-11-12T18:59:19.888307+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user *********@email.com
2018-11-12T18:59:19.867050+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 77ec2d50 by user *************@email.com
2018-11-12T18:59:25.456322+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node mp3.js`
2018-11-12T18:59:29.846039+00:00 heroku[web.1]: **State changed from starting to crashed**
2018-11-12T18:59:29.848349+00:00 heroku[web.1]: **State changed from crashed to starting**
2018-11-12T18:59:29.804086+00:00 heroku[web.1]: **Process exited with status 127**
2018-11-12T18:59:29.620089+00:00 app[web.1]: **bash: node: command not found**

Comment: Hmmm ... It seems heroku is not recognising your app as a node application. Do you have package.json in the root of your project?

Comment: No. I can see package-lock.json which got auto created at the time of project creation. There's no package.json

Comment: That's the problem! You must have the package.json file. Have you created your app using `npm init`?

Comment: If you use `npm init` you will start a wizard to create your package.json!

Comment: No. I manually created the .js file and launched the server using node filename.js

Comment: If you are working on your first node app for Heroku I'd strongly recommend you follow this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

Comment: Even after adding package.json and pushing it again to heroku repo and hit heroku open, facing the same issue - 

State changed from starting to crashed
2018-11-12T19:54:26.845321+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: node: command not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183513/discussion-between-beta-programmers-and-saulo).